# Mounting folder under ubuntu

Tags: linux, mount

I have a folder on my drive, which I would like to try mounting as a iso9660 cd. I've tried

```
mount -t iso9660 131/ ~/mnt/ -o loop
```

but mount complains that it is a folder. Is there any way to fake it into thinking it's a dvd? The contents a friend of mine copied are in fact dvd contents from a dvd, and I'd like to be able to view without opening up the "vob" files.

Any way to convince mount that a folder is a cd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most media programs will simply accept that a directory contains a DVD filesystem if you point them at it.

For example, VLC's "open DVD" can be used to browse to the folder and play it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Use VLC to open the folder as a disc.